# Form submit button not working and getting URL redirect error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm experiencing two form/redirect issues in deployment only (using Django) that could be related:

1. I have a form to create new blog posts which, upon hitting Submit, should redirect you to a url **based on the category selected in the form**. In production it works fine, but in deployment clicking the Submit button to create a new post does nothing (no redirect, form stays as is, nothing gets added elsewhere in the site) and nothing pops up on my error log. Note that I haven't set a value for "action=" in the form template and am not sure what (if anything) I should include to still allow me to redirect to different pages depending on the values in the form.
2. I can also edit a blog post which takes me to the form page with all the fields filled out. When I edit a value and hit Submit, it DOES update the blog post but redirects me to a page error: `Not Found: The requested URL /resources/books.views.resources was not found on this server.` If you check out the urls.py file, there is no "books.views.resources" url anywhere. Books is what I named the model. I'm not sure why in deployment this is getting added.

Would really appreciate any thoughts. Here's the relevant code:

**post_edit.html**

```
{% block content %}
<div id="content">
    <div class="padding">
        <h1>New post</h1>
            <form method="POST" class="progresstracker-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>

            </form>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^account/logout$', django.contrib.auth.views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'^blogtopics/computer-science/$', views.compsci, name='computer-science'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/data-science/$', views.datasci, name='data-science'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/other/$', views.other, name='other'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/$', views.blogtopics, name='blogtopics'),
    url(r'^resources/$', views.resources, name='resources'),
    url(r'^resources/edit/$', views.resources_post_edit, name='resources_post_edit'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^progresstracker/$', views.progresstracker, name='progresstracker'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.bt_detail, name='bt_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.pt_detail, name='pt_detail'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='bt_post_edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='pt_post_edit'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='bt_post_remove'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='pt_post_remove'),
    url(r'^blogtopics/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='bt_post_publish'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='pt_post_publish'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def resources(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug='resources')
    return render(request, 'blog/resources.html', {'post': post})

@login_required 
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            if post.category == 'progresstracker':
                return redirect('books.views.pt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
            elif post.category == 'resources':
                return redirect('books.views.resources')
            else:
                return redirect('books.views.bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required     
def post_edit(request, slug, category):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, category__slug=category)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            if post.category == 'progresstracker':
                return redirect('books.views.pt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
            elif post.category == 'resources':
                return redirect('books.views.resources')
            else:
                return redirect('books.views.bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)

    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required  
def resources_post_edit(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug='resources')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('books.views.resources')
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

For #1, check where - which view - handling the submitted form and check whats happening there.

For #2, 
In `redirect()` function call in your views, use view names defined in `urls.py` instead of python like view call.

For example, you have

```
return redirect('books.views.bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
```

So instead use

```
return redirect('bt_detail', slug=post.slug, category=post.category)
#---------------^
```

Comment: This did the trick for #2 - thanks! For #1, I notice it's only a problem when I create a new post - when I edit an existing post the Submit button works properly (saves and redirects). But I don't' see anything in the above posted "post_new" view that looks out of whack.